# Next free device option for qemu-nbd

Tags: qemu

Is there an option for the **qemu-nbd** command to get the next free, i.e. unused NBD like **losetup -f** does? The manpage of 0.0.1 (which is version of the currently stable release 1.7.0 of qemu) doesn't mention anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query attributes about nbd devices in sysfs.

For example:

```
cat /sys/class/block/nbd0/size
```

Will return 0, or the size of the mapped image file otherwise, if /dev/ndb0 is in use.

So you could iterate each device until you find one with 0 and attempt to try that with `qemu-nbd`.

Something like this should do it:

```sh
for x in /sys/class/block/nbd* ; do
  S=`cat $x/size`
  if [ "$S" == "0" ] ; then
    qemu-nbd -c /dev/`basename $x` some_file.img
    break
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for this useful workaround. I created a feature request under https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1296882

Comment: This does not work if the nbd device is connected to a backing file with zero length.

Answer (score 0):

According to
https://sourceforge.net/p/nbd/mailman/nbd-general/thread/CAONrwUFBRk2qLXF7qYmqsQ8x6Oa95Qc4yUgNTxOWZcaLzv0-TA%40mail.gmail.com/
I recommend something like following in `/bin/bash`:

```
# Of course this can be improved a lot, like returning after N NBDs found

get-free-nbds()
{
  local -n l="$1";
  local d;
  for d in /sys/block/nbd[0-9]*;
  do
    [ -r "$d" ] && [ ! -s "$d/pid" ] && l+=("/dev/${d##*/}");
  done;
  [ -n "$l" ];
}
```

Use it like that:

```
# put all free NBDs into array variable NBDs
get-free-nbds NBDs || { printf 'no free NBDs\n' >&2; exit 1; }

# check for 2 free NBDs
[ -n "${NBDs[1]}" ] || { printf 'we need 2 free NBDs, only %d free\n' "${#NDBs[@]}" >&2; exit 1; }

# Use them somewhere
use-nbds "${NBD[0]}" "${NBD[1]}"
```

As usual, there might be a race, as another process can grab the free NBD after it was detected as free.